# Using max function without grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three sets of information:

- productID
- date
- seller

I need to get information of last product sold for each `productID` and sold by. I tried using max value of date but that forces me to use grouping for seller as well but I don't want to group by seller. I want to group by `productID`, get the date it was sold last and by who. How can I avoid grouping on seller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Window function` which will help you to find the Latest date in each `group(productId)`

```
SELECT ProductID,
       [date],
       seller
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY ProductID
                   ORDER BY [date] desc) Rn,
               *
        FROM   tablename) a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or use can also use `Max aggregate` with `group by` to get the result

```
SELECT ProductID,
       [date],
       seller
FROM   tablename a
       JOIN (SELECT Max([date]) [date],
                    productid
             FROM   tablename
             group by productid) b
         ON a.productid = b.productid
            AND a.[date] = b.[date]
```

Comment: GREAT! thank you so much. I should definitely learn row_num function